# Topojson usage Error

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm, topojson

Hi I'm trying to use Topojson to convert shapefiles into topojson files.
When i try use Topojson the following error appears:

```
C:\>topojson
fs.js:0
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { // Copyright Joy
^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\dev\stdin'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:797:18)
at Object.module.exports [as readFileSync] (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\topojson\node_modules\rw\lib\rw\read-file-sync.js:5:10)
at inputJson (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\t
opojson:245:30)
at pop (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\node_module
s\queue-async\queue.js:24:14)
at Object.q.defer (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\
node_modules\queue-async\queue.js:55:11)
at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson:196
:5
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topoj
son\bin\topojson:195:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

I'm using windows 7 cmd to run this program, I already have reinstalled topojson, nodejs and npm to try to solve the problem.

I can't understand why the program is looking for files in C:\dev\stdin.

Can someone give a few tips? thanks in advance

Comment: Problem solved: clean the npm cache and redefine path of nodejs worked for me.

Comment: hitting the same problem – would be useful to know what you redefined the path to… .

Comment: I think you put null or wrong path of geojson file cause this error.
Please try some like
topojson  -o uk.json --id-property SU_A3  --properties name=NAME  -- subunits.json places.json
And please note that there is a ' ' between '--' and 'subunits.json'.